# How to draw near front clipping plane?

Tags: c, opengl-es

I am trying to draw object in OpenGL near front clipping plane. There is already defined path, and a camera is moving down the path. Now, I want to draw object that is moving with a camera, bot is not directly on front clipping plane.

I am using [Tux Racer](https://github.com/drodin/TuxRider) game port on Android and tried with small test function like this in hud.c:

```
void draw_triangle() {
    set_gl_options(FOG_PLANE);

    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glTranslatef(getparam_x_resolution() / 2.0, getparam_y_resolution() / 2.0, -5.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);          // Drawing Using Triangles
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f);      // Top
        glVertex3f(-50.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f);   // Bottom Left
        glVertex3f(50.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f);    // Bottom Right
        glEnd();                // Finished Drawing
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

but it wouldn't draw. Where am I getting wrong? I'm not shute if -5.0 for z-axis is too far, or I should use some other option for `set_gl_options()`, that is, I'm not shure what should be enabled/disabled from this options to see 3D object:

- GL_TEXTURE_2D
- GL_DEPTH_TEST
- GL_CULL_FACE
- GL_LIGHTING
- GL_NORMALIZE
- GL_ALPHA_TEST
- GL_BLEND
- GL_STENCIL_TEST
- GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S
- GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T
- GL_COLOR_MATERIAL

Other Functions:

- glDepthMask
- glShadeModel
- glDepthFunc

Here is code for setting camera view:

```
void update_view(player_data_t *plyr, scalar_t dt) {
    point_t view_pt;
    vector_t view_dir, up_dir, vel_dir, view_vec;
    scalar_t ycoord;
    scalar_t course_angle;
    vector_t axis;
    matrixgl_t rot_mat;
    vector_t y_vec;
    vector_t mz_vec;
    vector_t vel_proj;
    quaternion_t rot_quat;
    scalar_t speed;
    vector_t vel_cpy;
    scalar_t time_constant_mult;

    vel_cpy = plyr->vel;
    speed = normalize_vector(&vel_cpy);

    time_constant_mult =
            1.0
                    / min( 1.0,
                            max( 0.0,
                                    ( speed - NO_INTERPOLATION_SPEED ) /
                                    ( BASELINE_INTERPOLATION_SPEED - NO_INTERPOLATION_SPEED )));

    up_dir = make_vector(0, 1, 0);

    vel_dir = plyr->vel;
    normalize_vector(&vel_dir);

    course_angle = get_course_angle();

    switch (plyr->view.mode) {
    case TUXEYE: {
        .
.
.
        break;
    }
    case BEHIND: {
        /* Camera-on-a-string mode */

        /* Construct vector from player to camera */
        view_vec = make_vector(0, sin(ANGLES_TO_RADIANS(
                course_angle -
                CAMERA_ANGLE_ABOVE_SLOPE +
                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA )), cos(ANGLES_TO_RADIANS(
                course_angle -
                CAMERA_ANGLE_ABOVE_SLOPE +
                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA )));

        view_vec = scale_vector(CAMERA_DISTANCE, view_vec);

        y_vec = make_vector(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        mz_vec = make_vector(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
        vel_proj = project_into_plane(y_vec, vel_dir);

        normalize_vector(&vel_proj);

        /* Rotate view_vec so that it places the camera behind player */
        rot_quat = make_rotation_quaternion(mz_vec, vel_proj);

        view_vec = rotate_vector(rot_quat, view_vec);

        /* Construct view point */
        view_pt = move_point(plyr->pos, view_vec);

        /* Make sure view point is above terrain */
        ycoord = find_y_coord(view_pt.x, view_pt.z);

        if (view_pt.y < ycoord + MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
            view_pt.y = ycoord + MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT;
        }

        /* Interpolate view point */
        if (plyr->view.initialized) {
            /* Interpolate twice to get a second-order filter */
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                view_pt = interpolate_view_pos(plyr->pos, plyr->pos,
                        MAX_CAMERA_PITCH, plyr->view.pos, view_pt,
                        CAMERA_DISTANCE, dt,
                        BEHIND_ORBIT_TIME_CONSTANT * time_constant_mult);
            }
        }

        /* Make sure interpolated view point is above terrain */
        ycoord = find_y_coord(view_pt.x, view_pt.z);

        if (view_pt.y < ycoord + ABSOLUTE_MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
            view_pt.y = ycoord + ABSOLUTE_MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT;
        }

        /* Construct view direction */
        view_vec = subtract_points(view_pt, plyr->pos);

        axis = cross_product(y_vec, view_vec);
        normalize_vector(&axis);

        make_rotation_about_vector_matrix(rot_mat, axis,
                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA);
        view_dir = scale_vector(-1.0, transform_vector(rot_mat, view_vec));

        /* Interpolate orientation of camera */
        if (plyr->view.initialized) {
            /* Interpolate twice to get a second-order filter */
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                interpolate_view_frame(plyr->view.up, plyr->view.dir, &up_dir,
                        &view_dir, dt, BEHIND_ORIENT_TIME_CONSTANT);
                up_dir = make_vector(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            }
        }

        break;
    }

    case FOLLOW: {
        /* Camera follows player (above and behind) */

        up_dir = make_vector(0, 1, 0);

        /* Construct vector from player to camera */
        view_vec = make_vector(0, sin(ANGLES_TO_RADIANS(
                course_angle -
                CAMERA_ANGLE_ABOVE_SLOPE +
                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA )), cos(ANGLES_TO_RADIANS(
                course_angle -
                CAMERA_ANGLE_ABOVE_SLOPE +
                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA )));
        view_vec = scale_vector(CAMERA_DISTANCE, view_vec);

        y_vec = make_vector(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        mz_vec = make_vector(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
        vel_proj = project_into_plane(y_vec, vel_dir);

        normalize_vector(&vel_proj);

        /* Rotate view_vec so that it places the camera behind player */
        rot_quat = make_rotation_quaternion(mz_vec, vel_proj);

        view_vec = rotate_vector(rot_quat, view_vec);

        /* Construct view point */
        view_pt = move_point(plyr->pos, view_vec);

        /* Make sure view point is above terrain */
        ycoord = find_y_coord(view_pt.x, view_pt.z);

        if (view_pt.y < ycoord + MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
            view_pt.y = ycoord + MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT;
        }

        /* Interpolate view point */
        if (plyr->view.initialized) {
            /* Interpolate twice to get a second-order filter */
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                view_pt = interpolate_view_pos(plyr->view.plyr_pos, plyr->pos,
                        MAX_CAMERA_PITCH, plyr->view.pos, view_pt,
                        CAMERA_DISTANCE, dt,
                        FOLLOW_ORBIT_TIME_CONSTANT * time_constant_mult);
            }
        }

        /* Make sure interpolate view point is above terrain */
        ycoord = find_y_coord(view_pt.x, view_pt.z);

        if (view_pt.y < ycoord + ABSOLUTE_MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
            view_pt.y = ycoord + ABSOLUTE_MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT;
        }

        /* Construct view direction */
        view_vec = subtract_points(view_pt, plyr->pos);

        axis = cross_product(y_vec, view_vec);
        normalize_vector(&axis);

        make_rotation_about_vector_matrix(rot_mat, axis,
                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA);
        view_dir = scale_vector(-1.0, transform_vector(rot_mat, view_vec));

        /* Interpolate orientation of camera */
        if (plyr->view.initialized) {
            /* Interpolate twice to get a second-order filter */
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                interpolate_view_frame(plyr->view.up, plyr->view.dir, &up_dir,
                        &view_dir, dt, FOLLOW_ORIENT_TIME_CONSTANT);
                up_dir = make_vector(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            }
        }

        break;
    }

    case ABOVE: {
        /* Camera always uphill of player */

        up_dir = make_vector(0, 1, 0);

        /* Construct vector from player to camera */
        view_vec = make_vector(0, sin(ANGLES_TO_RADIANS(
                course_angle -
                CAMERA_ANGLE_ABOVE_SLOPE+
                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA )), cos(ANGLES_TO_RADIANS(
                course_angle -
                CAMERA_ANGLE_ABOVE_SLOPE+
                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA )));
        view_vec = scale_vector(CAMERA_DISTANCE, view_vec);

        /* Construct view point */
        view_pt = move_point(plyr->pos, view_vec);

        /* Make sure view point is above terrain */
        ycoord = find_y_coord(view_pt.x, view_pt.z);

        if (view_pt.y < ycoord + MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
            view_pt.y = ycoord + MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT;
        }

        /* Construct view direction */
        view_vec = subtract_points(view_pt, plyr->pos);

        make_rotation_matrix(rot_mat, PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA, 'x');
        view_dir = scale_vector(-1.0, transform_vector(rot_mat, view_vec));

        break;
    }

    case BIRDEYE: {
        /* Camera always uphill of player */

        up_dir = make_vector(0, 1, 0);

        /* Construct vector from player to camera */
        /*sin(ANGLES_TO_RADIANS(
                                        course_angle -
                                        CAMERA_ANGLE_ABOVE_SLOPE+
                                        PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA ))
                                        */
        /*cos(ANGLES_TO_RADIANS(
                                                course_angle -
                                                CAMERA_ANGLE_ABOVE_SLOPE+
                                                PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA ))
                                                */
        view_vec = make_vector(0, 3, -0.5);
        view_vec = scale_vector(CAMERA_DISTANCE, view_vec);

        /* Construct view point */
        view_pt = move_point(plyr->pos, view_vec);

        /* Make sure view point is above terrain */
        ycoord = find_y_coord(view_pt.x, view_pt.z);

        if (view_pt.y < ycoord + MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
            view_pt.y = ycoord + MIN_CAMERA_HEIGHT;
        }

        /* Construct view direction */
        view_vec = subtract_points(view_pt, plyr->pos);

        make_rotation_matrix(rot_mat, PLAYER_ANGLE_IN_CAMERA, 'x');
        view_dir = scale_vector(-1.0, transform_vector(rot_mat, view_vec));

        break;
    }
    default:
        code_not_reached();
        break;
    }

    /* Create view matrix */
    plyr->view.pos = view_pt;
    plyr->view.dir = view_dir;
    plyr->view.up = up_dir;
    plyr->view.plyr_pos = plyr->pos;
    plyr->view.initialized = True;

    setup_view_matrix(plyr);
}
```

### UPDATE

Solved!, The problem was in using OpenGL instead OpenGL ES.

Comment: Could you show the code that sets up your camera ?

Comment: Well, I am using port of Tux Racer for Android. I want to add some new objects to a game, both on path and in the air. Source of a game is on GitHub: [TuxRider](https://github.com/drodin/TuxRider). I could put some more code here, but I really don't know what you need so you could help me.

Comment: To begin with, just the code where you set up your camera, whatever method you use to do so. I can't say for sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android uses OpenGL ES, which doesn't support glBegin() and glEnd(), so your code is not going to draw anything. You need to use Vertex Buffer Objects to draw objects.

A classic guide to VBOs is here: http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=45

but you may find that googling "Android OpenGL tutorial" will provide some simpler guides.

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful, but still I can't make it run. Now, when using glVertexPointer() and glColorPointer() in this function, it blocks a race. I'll try to debug in what specific time it does. But, anyway this was very helpful. If I succeed, you'll get a bounty.

Comment: I solved a problem! It would took me longer, without a help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well, if you want to display something just in front of the camera, all the camera setup code is irrelevant; moreover, you need to make sure that it does not apply to your triangle, that is, you call to drawTriangle() from somewhere where the matrix stack is empty. where do you call it from now? I went to GitHub to look at TuxRider and got lost, sorry.

after that, if you render a triangle in screen coordinates, it might be worth taking into account that they range from -1 to +1 - your geometry of 50 by 50 at 5 away is too big and too far away.

Bests of luck

Comment: Well, I tried to call it from racing_loop() after update_view() procedure, but it doesn't work. I also tried in draw_hud() which draws all 2D things on front clipping plane - it works when I translate to (x, y, 0.0), but only then.